# Weird MongoDB Error PHP

Tags: php, forms, mongodb, text

I have been using MongoDB and PHP for a few months now.  I am doing some testing on a couple new features, out of nowhere MongoDB is acting weird.  It is truncating the first character in a string when I insert it into the Database.  My code has not changed, only the results?
I have a text form called details.
When I submit and insert it into the collection, the details entries gets all screwy.
If I enter "Tomato" into the form, I will receive:

From PHP echo (building from a query for the entry after insertion):

```
"omato"
```

From the Mongo Shell I receive:

```
"Details" : ""
```

From an api request (echos JSON) I receive:

```
"Details" : "\u0000omato"
```

Any thoughts on what is causing this?

Comment: Hmmmm, funny thing.  All works perfectly again.  If anyone reads this, has anyone had random errors like this from Mongo before?  Seems a bit sketchy?

Comment: any os updates happen during this timespam?

Comment: Nope.  Simply removed all entries from the database, and began to enter new ones to test.  Really weird.

Comment: Can you post some sample code that demos the problem?  Also, are you using the MongoDB driver directly, or via a PHP framework?

Comment: I can't provide any code that demonstrates this.  It was a basic html form, and basic $_POST in PHP that retrieved it.  I had used the code for weeks without such an error, then it just started happening randomly?  Few minutes later, it was back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have for some reason added a `\0` character to a string. The three different tools handle this all in different ways:

1. PHP's echo simply displays it, and hence it doesn't appear. If you'd stream the output through something like `hexdump` you'll see the `\0` character.
2. The mongo shell truncates the display when it encounters the `\0` character, and hence you see nothing.
3. PHP's JSON encoder encodes a `\0` character as "\u0000".

Comment: I think it might have had something to do with Virgina EC2 coverage.  It was experiencing errors during the same time I was getting this weird error.  I never changed the code, it just work, didn't, and has been working again since.